# Display a div based on condition (whether ul has child)

Tags: c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

please refer to the code attached below. 
I would like to display the #non-alphabet if .refinement-options does not has child (brand-option). 
How can I do that ?

*See further explanation below.

```
<div class="alphabets-container">
                <div owl-carousel owl-configuration='{"items" : 27, "itemsDesktopSmall" : [992,20], "itemsTablet" : [768,10], "itemsMobile" : [479, 10], "itemsDesktopMedium" : [1200,27], "itemsDesktop" : false, "pagination" : false, "autoPlay" : false}'>

                    <div class="list-item" id="non-alphabet"><a ng-class="{active : isAlphabetSelected('#')}" ng-click="filterBrand('#')">#</a></div>

                    @foreach (var character in brandCategories)
                    {
                        <div class="list-item">
                            <a class="alphabet-option" ng-class="{active : isAlphabetSelected('@character')}" ng-click="filterBrand('@character')">@character</a>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul class="refinement-options reflex-container reflex-wrap filter-group" data-filter-type="brand">
                <li class="brand-option reflex-col-3" ng-repeat="item in items | startsWithLetter:filterKey">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" ng-checked="item.IsChecked" ng-model="item.IsChecked" id="{{ item.Id }}" name="{{ item.Name }}" value="{{ item.QueryValue }}" data-base-url="{{ item.BaseUrl }}" data-link-url="{{ item.LinkUrl }}" />
                    <label for="{{ item.Id }}" class="checkbox css-label">{{ item.DisplayText }} ( {{ item.HitCount }} )</label>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

[image]

**No options in '#' tab, therefore I want the '#' be removed or hidden if it's empty**
[image: No options in '#' tab, there]

## I did something like this using ng-show, but it did not work as expected. Please correct me.

**At the controller**

```
$scope.showLetter = function() {
        if ($('.brand-option').length == 0){
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    };
```

**Markup**

```
<div class="list-item" id="non-alphabet" ng-show="showLetter()"><a ng-class="{active : isAlphabetSelected('#')}" ng-click="filterBrand('#')" ng-disabled="">#</a></div>
```

Comment: What does items in ng-repeat look like?

Comment: @garethb it's the options available that starts with the respective alphabets.

Answer (score 1):

Use ng-show on the div with a function that works out whether to show or not.

```
<div class="list-item" id="non-alphabet" ng-show="showHash()"><a ng-class="{active : isAlphabetSelected('#')}" ng-click="filterBrand('#')">#</a></div>
```

And in your angular controller something like this. Go through each item and if any item does not start with a letter, show the #

```
$scope.showHash= function(){
    var r = /^[^a-zA-Z]/g; //regex for not start with letter 
    $.each($scope.items, function(index, value){
        if (r.test(value.DisplayText)){
            return true;
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I wanted to hide "#non-alphabet" div (the line before @foreach)

Comment: I've tried to use ng-show (see my edited post above) but did not work as expected. Hope for your help. Thanks.